# Fourier Smoothing of Time-Series data in R using FFT function

Tags: r, fft

I am trying to apply `FFT` function on time series data to smooth it in R:
Sampling time = `16 days`
time period = `1 year`

Input Values:

```
x <-c(5292,5324,4560,5479,5426,5836,6020,6163,5582,5530,6656,8473,8685,8107,8296,7943,7358,6476,5557,5057,4962,5038,5592)
```

The result was `complex number` in the form of `ai+b`:

```
fft(x)
 [1] 143412.0000+   0.0000i -16172.9339+5204.3716i   3840.8982-7231.4595i
 [4]   -168.9544+4101.8545i   3964.4752+1373.7454i  -2129.1013- 412.7717i
 [7]   2043.0532+1519.1651i    -92.0472- 889.5815i    659.5677+ 106.7809i
[10]   -790.6303- 560.5901i   -421.6175- 712.4884i  -1580.7096- 338.9213i
[13]  -1580.7096+ 338.9213i   -421.6175+ 712.4884i   -790.6303+ 560.5901i
[16]    659.5677- 106.7809i    -92.0472+ 889.5815i   2043.0532-1519.1651i
[19]  -2129.1013+ 412.7717i   3964.4752-1373.7454i   -168.9544-4101.8545i
[22]   3840.8982+7231.4595i -16172.9339-5204.3716i
```

Now I want to smooth the data upto `2 harmonics,` and don't know how to proceed further in R. I searched the internet thoroughly but couldn't find my answer. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Two harmonics of what frequency?

Comment: The time series is in 16 days interval for 1 year.